# How do I select x and y coordinates from a column in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[events DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGGXt.png)

I converted and merged multiple json files into one DataFrame, and I am trying to select the x-coordinate from a column that has location. The data is in [x,y] format within the column. I'm just not sure what type it is, because I tried splitting the "location" column into "location.x" and "location.y" using this method, but I guess it doesnt work due to having NaN values in the column:

`events['location.x'], events['location.y'] = zip(*events['location'])`

but it returned a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Here is my code:

```
path = os.fspath(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Football Data\Euro2020Matches")
json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.json"))
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
  
  
# loop over the list of json files
for f in json_files:
      
    # read the json file
    events = pd.read_json(f)
      
    # print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
      
    # print the content
    print('Content:')
    display(events)
    print()
```

```
dfs = []
for file in json_files:
    with open(file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        json_data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(f.read()))
    dfs.append(json_data)
events = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
```

I just want to be able to pick the x coordinate and the y coordinate to make the code below work. I also have a "pass.end_location" column.

```
events['initialDistancefromgoal'] = np.sqrt(((120 - events['location.x'])**2) + ((40 -events['location.y'])**2))
events['finalDistancefromgoal'] = np.sqrt(((120 - events['pass.end_location.x'])**2) + ((40 - events['pass.end_location.y'])**2))


events['finalDistancefromgoalcarry'] = np.sqrt(((120 - events['carry.end_location.x'])**2) + ((40 - events['carry.end_location.y'])**2))
```

Comment: It's impossible to know with how little you've given us in reproducibility, but try: `events['location.x'], events['location.y'] = events['location'].str[0], events['location'].str[1]` instead.

Comment: Or `events[['location.x', 'location.y']] = events.apply(lambda x: x['location'], axis=1, result_type='expand')`

Comment: my apologies, it is my first time posting. I just edited my post to show everything I have entered.

Comment: The first solution works! Thank you so much! so basically the x and y coordinates were strings?

Comment: The x/y coordinates appear to be a list formatted `[x, y]`, the `str` accessor also applies to lists, so `str[0]` is extracting the first value in the list~